# custom order of products in woocommerce category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have a woocommerce store and want to make a custom order of my products. 
Users access directly category pages, no shop archive page.

Do you have any good solutions for making a custom order here ? 
I Tried using plugins and also giving those products a number... but all did not work.

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a number to each woocommerce product in wp-admin.When you edit or add product than you will see a **menu order** option just input a numeric number.